# Leaflet - draggable marker and coordinates display in a field form

Tags: leaflet

I have to do a draggable marker and its coordinates should be displayed in fields. It will be a part of a contact form in PHP. I created a draggable marker, help me what to do now.

```
var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(53.471, 18.744), {
draggable: true
}).addTo(map);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xTh5U/

Here is example in Google Maps API, I need the same in Leaflet.

Comment: iH8 helped me solving a problem.
Solution is there: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271994/leaflet-draggable-marker-and-coordinates-display-in-a-field-form

Answer (score 2):

Use dragend method for the marker. Look through the jsfiddle.I hope it helps.
http://jsfiddle.net/Poshan/w6ej59jk/5/

Comment: You solved half of my problem - how to receive cooordinates from dragged marker. Now I need to do the second part of Google Maps API example - how to display the coordinates in field form.

Comment: That's what `addToTextBox()` accomplishes.  Just add add the ids `lat` and `lng` to two elements in your form, or combine them using something like `[lt, ln].join(', ')`